# How to provide a Spring @Bean to a Java 9 module (provides ... with ...)

Tags: java, spring, java-9, java-module

Is there a (clean) way to provide an initialized Spring Bean as a service implementation in a Java 9 module ?

The best solution I think of right now is :

**module-info.java**

```java
module my.module {
   provides Service with ServiceWrapper;
}
```

**Service.java**

```
public interface Service {
    void doSomething();
}
```

**ServiceImpl.java**

```
@Component
public class ServiceImpl implements Service, InitializingBean {

    @Autowired SomeDependency dep;

    public void doSomething() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        ServiceWrapper.INSTANCE.set(() -> this);
    }

}
```

**ServiceWrapper.java**

```
public class ServiceWrapper implements Service {

    static final ServiceWrapper INSTANCE = new ServiceWrapper();

    private Supplier<Service> supplier;

    void set(Supplier<Service> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        this.supplier.get().doSomething();
    }

    public static Service provider() {
        return ServiceWrapper.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```